# How to create DB in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am implementing one project in which i have to create multimapping  tables.

```
@Entity
public class UserBuilding {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int userBuildingId;
    @OneToOne
    private User user;

    private HashMap<Building,ArrayList<Horizontal>> userWork;
}
```

this is my entity class and i want to create table for this.
User and Building and Horizontals are also entities.

```
private HashMap<Building,ArrayList<Horizontal>> userWork;
```

one Buidling can have multiple Horizontals.
i am confused what annotations i should write to create above relation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can directly accomplish a Map of collections. At least not without creating your own custom hibernate user-type.

Depending on your model, you may want to consider directly associating your collection of horizontals with the `Building` entity and placing a set of `Building` entities in `UserBuilding` rather than a map. This will probably give you the same model benefits for less trouble.

If you have to have a map, a common work-around would be to create an intermediary entity for `ArrayList<Horizontal>` such as `HorizontalCollection`.